# Users can't upload image to my website

Tags: php, html

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP file(upload.php):

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'new/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . 
basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded. $uploadfile \n";
} else {
echo "Upload failed";
}
echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

Im useing this php code. But after uploading it  shows that it failed. Why it's failing. Here is an demo test, http://labrat.herobo.com/g.html

Comment: I've seen this piece code so many times, I know it by heart. You  have syntax errors; check for them.

Comment: What's the error message on failure?

Comment: [...undefined index............ ^](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Failure msg: Upload failed, this is one i put as a else

Answer (score 2):

No input tag is associated with `userfile`.

Please change

```
$_FILES['userfile'] to $_FILES['fileToUpload']
```

OR

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"> to <input type="file" name="userfile" id="fileToUpload">
```